# Can't Install/Update packages on newly installed CentOS

Tags: networking, centos, package-management, yum

I installed CentOS6 and it is the first time. I tried to install/update packages.
But I coudn't.
Here is the output and it doesn't stop. How can I solve this?

```
[root@localhost suranga]# yum update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.nus.edu.sg
 * extras: mirror.nus.edu.sg
 * updates: mirror.nus.edu.sg
base                                                     | 3.7 kB     00:00     
http: //mirror.nus.edu.sg/centos/6.0/os/i386/repodata/2b014e1fcde80ec1cc69d6a048f260f712b1ae2d83d1fc04d3b3c00ade817ec9-primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 12] Timeout on http: //mirror.nus.edu.sg/centos/6.0/os/i386/repodata/2b014e1fcde80ec1cc69d6a048f260f712b1ae2d83d1fc04d3b3c00ade817ec9-primary.sqlite.bz2: (28, '')
Trying other mirror.
http: //centosmirror.go4hosting.in/centos/6.0/os/i386/repodata/2b014e1fcde80ec1cc69d6a048f260f712b1ae2d83d1fc04d3b3c00ade817ec9-primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 12] Timeout on http: //centosmirror.go4hosting.in/centos/6.0/os/i386/repodata/2b014e1fcde80ec1cc69d6a048f260f712b1ae2d83d1fc04d3b3c00ade817ec9-primary.sqlite.bz2: (28, '')
Trying other mirror.
http: //mirrors.ispros.com.bd/centos/6.0/os/i386/repodata/2b014e1fcde80ec1cc69d6a048f260f712b1ae2d83d1fc04d3b3c00ade817ec9-primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 12] Timeout on http: //mirrors.ispros.com.bd/centos/6.0/os/i386/repodata/2b014e1fcde80ec1cc69d6a048f260f712b1ae2d83d1fc04d3b3c00ade817ec9-primary.sqlite.bz2: (28, '')
Trying other mirror.
http: //mirror.vietoss.com/CentOS/6.0/os/i386/repodata/2b014e1fcde80ec1cc69d6a048f260f712b1ae2d83d1fc04d3b3c00ade817ec9-primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 12] Timeout on http: //mirror.vietoss.com/CentOS/6.0/os/i386/repodata/2b014e1fcde80ec1cc69d6a048f260f712b1ae2d83d1fc04d3b3c00ade817ec9-primary.sqlite.bz2: (28, '')
Trying other mirror.
http: //centos.vr-zone.com/6.0/os/i386/repodata/2b014e1fcde80ec1cc69d6a048f260f712b1ae2d83d1fc04d3b3c00ade817ec9-primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 12] Timeout on http: //centos.vr-zone.com/6.0/os/i386/repodata/2b014e1fcde80ec1cc69d6a048f260f712b1ae2d83d1fc04d3b3c00ade817ec9-primary.sqlite.bz2: (28, '')
Trying other mirror.
http: //ftp.cuhk.edu.hk/pub/Linux/centos/6.0/os/i386/repodata/2b014e1fcde80ec1cc69d6a048f260f712b1ae2d83d1fc04d3b3c00ade817ec9-primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 12] Timeout on http: //ftp.cuhk.edu.hk/pub/Linux/centos/6.0/os/i386/repodata/2b014e1fcde80ec1cc69d6a048f260f712b1ae2d83d1fc04d3b3c00ade817ec9-primary.sqlite.bz2: (28, '')
Trying other mirror.
http: //mirror-fpt-telecom.fpt.net/centos/6.0/os/i386/repodata/2b014e1fcde80ec1cc69d6a048f260f712b1ae2d83d1fc04d3b3c00ade817ec9-primary.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 12] Timeout on http: //mirror-fpt-telecom.fpt.net/centos/6.0/os/i386/repodata/2b014e1fcde80ec1cc69d6a048f260f712b1ae2d83d1fc04d3b3c00ade817ec9-primary.sqlite.bz2: (28, '')
Trying other mirror.
```

Answer (score 4):

The URL's you're seeing are just URL's that you need to be able to pull up on your browser, and traverse.   I grabbed the first URL and started going down the chain until I got to http://mirror.nus.edu.sg/centos/6.0/.  Therein was a readme file containing this

> This directory (and version of CentOS) is depreciated.  For normal users,
>   you should use /6/ and not /6.0/ in your path. Please see this FAQ
>   concerning the CentOS release scheme:
>
> http://www.centos.org/modules/smartfaq/faq.php?faqid=34
>
> If you know what you are doing, and absolutely want to remain at the 6.0
>   level, go to http://vault.centos.org/ for packages. Please keep in mind that 6.0 no longer gets any updates

So it looks like you've got an outdated repo list.  Edit your repos (/etc/yum.repos.d/) and change the 6.0 to 6.  Then take those URL's and traverse them to see if they'll take you to the right place.  If not, search the web for an updated repo list.

CentOS points the centos/6 directory to whatever the newest point release is. 6.1 is just considered a patched version of 6.0, and what they consider "6".

Answer (score 4):

```
$ sudo yum clean all

$ sudo yum update
```

Repeat 2 times if needed.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. Here is a little secret to getting a badge - go to this link and read the page http://unix.stackexchange.com/about.

Answer (score 0):

There's some problem with your network settings and/or connection. Try to (re)configure network interface. As a first step you might want to run 'netstat -i -e' to list interfaces and make sure they've assigned correct ip addresses.

Comment: They work fine. I can brows the internet.

Comment: Can you open http://mirror.nus.edu.sg/centos/ in your browser? Are you using any sort of proxy server?

Comment: [http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6.0/os/i386/repodata/2b014e1fcde80ec1cc69d6a048f260f712b1ae2d83d1fc04d3b3c00ade817ec9-primary.sqlite.bz2](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6.0/os/i386/repodata/2b014e1fcde80ec1cc69d6a048f260f712b1ae2d83d1fc04d3b3c00ade817ec9-primary.sqlite.bz2) I tried this one on the browser and I couldn't download it manually. I'm not using a proxy server.

Answer (score 0):

edit your repo setting file at `/etc/yum.repos.d/` (there you can find files for each repo that you connect), and uncomment in these files the line that start with `#baseurl` and comment the line that start with `mirrorlist`.

Comment: I did it. Still same